# Variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$ spreading uniquely

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a smooth proper variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Assume that there is a proper flat family over $\mathbb{Z}$ that has $V$ as the fiber over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Assume moreover that any two such families have isomorphic function fields.

Is $V$ a projective space then?

Comment: No the projective line also has this property.

Comment: @DanielLoughran you are right I totally forgot

Comment: @DanielLoughran Can't we obtain another lift of the projective space by considering an integral model of a Severi-Brauer variety corresponding to a non-trivial division algebra over Q that splits at p?

Comment: @SashaP: Apologies you are correct. I read family over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ instead of over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Im which case, to get a counter-example, it seems that one should look at varieties with no deformations and no automorphisms.

Comment: Maybe a toric variety with no deformations and no non-toric automorphisms could do the trick. (By Hilbert's theorem 90, there are no nontrivial $\mathbb G_m$-torsors over fields, so you don't have to worry about twists). I don't know if such varieties exist but both deformations and automorphisms of toric varieties have a combinatorial description so one could search for this.

Comment: A rigid Calabi-Yau threefold with no automorphisms would also do the trick, I believe.

Comment: @DanielLoughran What happens if there are automorphisms? You mean it can be like a non-trivial vector bundle over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: In the presence of automorphisms your variety will have twists (like in the case of the projective line).